# How can I get rid of devices and mounted partitions in unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, devices

The following used to work:

> gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices devices-option "Never"

But after I reinstalled yesterday the devices-option key is gone and so it fails.
dconf-editor only shows that the key is not there, but doesn't allow me to create one.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is available via the CompizConfig Settings Manager.  If you install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package and run `ccsm` (or find it in the launcher), the "Experimental" tab of the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" module gives you the options of "Always", "Only Mounted", and "Never".

Comment: Thank you, that worked so far, those 'normal' partitions and devices are gone from the launcher. But two (encrypted) device mapper partitions still show up as question marks. So I leave this open for now, would be nice to get rid of them too. (sry for my poor english:)

Answer (score 0):

as far as internal partitions (drives), it's an option - the default has been changed to 'OnlyMounted'
If this is what you are referring to it can be changed in dconf-editor or gsettings in a limited fashion
~$

```
gsettings range com.canonical.Unity.Devices devices-option
enum
'Never'
'OnlyMounted'
'Always'

gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices devices-option Always
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I have no key 'devices-option', that's what 'gesettings range...' is telling me too. And I don't know how to recreate it (or why it's gone, I reinstalled and updated yesterday)